# Avoid MemcacheService race condition in email service

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

Image my server provides an email service that I am using memcache for. When a sender sends a new email to user X, the key for X is removed from the cache. When user X makes a call to `getInbox` the response is added to the cache under the key for X (so that the same response is returned for subsequent calls to getInbox until a sender removes the key and the process continues). So a very simple design. But what happens when X is reading at the same time that some sender is sending X an email? Per my understanding putIfUntouched and getIdentifiable do not help here. As they seem to only work if I am using in putIfUntouched the exact same instance/value returned by getIdentifiable, which is not possible in my case since I am talking about two different service calls. So does anyone know how I might avoid race conditions in my simple model?

**update**

In light of @AndreiVolgin's response, let me add details to what I perceive to be the race condition:

Sender's job is to remove the key; recipient's job is to 1) read the value with `syncCache.get(key)`, 2) if the value is null then set the key to a real value with `syncCache.put(key, value)`. The problem is in the case where send is trying to set the value to null while at the same time recipient is calling `syncCache.put(key, value)`. If recipient wins in setting to `value` then recipient may never get to see the change made by sender.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a race condition. A user will simply not see a message sent to him a few milliseconds before he checked his Inbox.

There is no way to avoid that, and there is no reason to avoid that. What if a message is delivered 1 ms after your Memcache call as opposed to 1 ms before this Memcache call? Won't a user be equally upset?

UPDATE:

Based on OP comments, one process sets a flag (no new massages) using a memcache, while another process removes it when a new message arrives. If a new message fails to remove the flag because it coincided with a user setting a flag, a new message will be invisible until the next message arrives.

While extremely rare, this is a valid concern. The solution, in my opinion, is to set an expiration time on flags as a fail-safe for this rare condition.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I am worried about the case where the sender fails to remove the key because of interleaving, in which case no number of pull-to-refresh from the recipient will deliver the new message. In this case if no additional new message is delivered for days, that last delivered message will never be seen by the recipient

Comment: You can set an expiration time on keys in Memcache. You are describing a very rare use case, so setting an expiration date will serve as a fail-safe for such situations.

Comment: Thanks again. If that's the only way, then that's that. The thing is memcache has the potential of saving me a lot of money and setting a sensible expiration date just throws a wrench in my design. On another note, while this concurrency error may seem a rare case, the problem in my case is not so much frequency of occurrence but potential damaging effect to the individuals affected. But then maybe I can afford to piss off a few users.

Comment: You can calculate the probability. Also, the expiration time will affect only accounts that receive no messages during the expiration time. As for the costs, use a keys-only query that costs almost nothing now. In this case, you don't even need to use memcache.

Comment: I am not sure a keys only query would work here since I am checking if a particular user has received mail since timestamp x. In my understanding, keys only queries don't take conditions. am I wrong about that?

Comment: Keys-only queries can have all the same parameters and sort orders as regular queries. The only difference is that they return keys only instead of complete entities. In your case, however, you can use regular query: it will cost very little if it comes back empty.